# C bindings to Ada package

Tags: c, binding, ada

While I can find plenty of information on generating Ada bindings to C libraries, I can't seem to find anything on the opposite. Specifically, I have some math/science packages that I would like to export to C, to make them more widely usable. Exporting functions or procedures through pragmas/aspects is easy enough, but I'm confused about how to deal with types declared in Ada.

Say, for example, I have a package implementing unit-agnostic planar angles. Along with arithmetic operators, there are functions for handling the different units, like Degrees(«Value») return «Angle» as a constructor and Gradians(«Angle») return «Value» as an accessor. This way, there's a common representation, carefully picked, to allow the programmer to work with any unit.

What I'm confused about, is when the functions or procedures are exported, how does C also know and understand the angle type that it is to pass?

Edit:
Okay, so I was adding "with Export, Convention => C;" to the types, when there should not have been an "Export". Silly oversight.

Still closely related, I now don't know how to actually call the code from C. As stated, there's plenty of documentation about importing stuff from C, but even the LRM doesn't provide examples about exporting stuff to C.

I know C includes libraries/files through the preprocessor, specifically "#include" directives. I wouldn't think this would work though, as the C compiler would then try to parse the Ada spec. How does C then see the Ada stuff?

Comment: You don't tell C what the Ada type looks like.  You tell Ada to represent the type in a way that is usable by a C program, by using the C `Convention` aspect, for one.  Representation clauses help also, so that you can tell Ada to lay out types in a specific way;  that way you can force it to look the same as a similar C `struct`.  See http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html for more info.  Be careful about using Ada access types; Ada provides `Interfaces.C.Pointers` to declare types that will be compatible with C pointers.

Comment: If you run into difficulties, post some specific Ada code that you want to be usable from C.

Comment: @ajb: Ada stuff compiles fine now, but I don't know how to get C to recognize the Ada defined stuff. See edit for details. I figured the problem was generic enough that no source was necessary. If I am wrong, I'll post source.

Comment: It would help for you to post source.  But the bottom line is that your question is wrong; you **cannot** get C to see the Ada stuff, except for the  `External_Name` or `Link_Name` of your subprogram.  Or if your Ada compiler comes with a tool to generate C `.h` files, then your C program can #include those.  In general, though, you have to write C versions of the types, then use Ada aspects, pragmas, and representation clauses to make sure the representations match.  If you're not sure how, post some code.

Comment: Do not forget also about elaboration for the Ada code. You will need to have your C program call the generated elaboration subprograms (adainit and adafinal). The simplest here is to build via project files, and look up the documentation for "standalone libraries".